# How to encourage people to use the chat more

Tags: discussion, chat

The chat is a good place for users to ask some little hints, and get fast answers when people are online. There is one suggestion mechanism for chatting:

- If comments go more moving it to the chat are options is displaying to the users.

One important thing about using chat or asking a question is that, if the question is even a detailed question and other people will get benefit from it, it should be asked on an SE site, instead of being asked in chat.

However, I see people trying to ask questions, even when they want to discuss about something (not a question style as like brain storming). On the other hand, I see that people are not using chat much. If we encourage people to use the chat, they can make brain storming there, and have a chance to get ideas from a large group, and can get instant answers on every topic.

What do you think about it, and how can we have a much better chat mechanism?

Answer (score 3):

If you see a question that just leads to discussion, is *not constructive* as defined in the FAQ, then we should:

- downvote it
- close it
- tell the OP to go discuss on chat if they like
- (eventually delete the question)

People have to be reinforced to do something they wouldn't naturally do. If you "punish" them, they'll learn what to do in such a case – i.e. stop posting subjective discussion-style questions and go discuss with others on chat.

Of course, that only works if they really want to. You can't force them to use chat either, but at least we should prevent such questions from being asked in the first place.

Comment: Actually I am not wondering about people who uses answer-question part as a chat place. I just want to people at chat place for another type of discussion place different from there. I don't think that chat rooms works well right now. Maybe people can be awarded there more or any other ideas.

Comment: @kamaci I don't quite understand. See, you can't force people to use chat. It's a direct medium where you have to actively participate. Are you saying that you just *generally* want more people to chat?

Comment: I just want to make chat place into an active discussion place for brain storming

Comment: @kamaci Any concrete ideas how chat needs to be adapted for this? I regularly use chat on Super User, and it works quite well.

Comment: Stackoverflow is the biggest part of SO however a big website as like SO is so so poor at chat part. There can organize big brain storming parties and people can invite there at main page.